# Setting arbitrary CSS rules using JavaScript in JavaFX's WebView

Tags: java, javascript, css, webkit, javafx

I am using `WebView` in fullscreen to display content that has a fixed size of `1024x768`, therefore I need to scale it so that it stretches from top to bottom of the screen. To accomplish that, I have put the following code in my controller's `initialize()`:

```
this.wv.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<State>() {
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> ov, State oldState, State newState)
    {
        if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED)
        {
            wv.requestFocus();
            wv.getEngine().setUserStyleSheetLocation(getClass().getResource("/css/user.css").toExternalForm());
            Rectangle2D primaryScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
            Element maincontainer = (Element) wv.getEngine().executeScript("document.getElementById('pbody')");
            maincontainer.setAttribute("style", String.format("-webkit-transform: scale(%.5f)", (primaryScreenBounds.getHeight() / 768.0)));
        }
        else if (newState == State.FAILED)
        {
            //.
        }
    }
});
```

The CSS in `user.css` loads fine and for reference here is the code:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#pbody {
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
}
```

In the HTML the body tag definitely has an id:

```
<body id="pbody">
```

The problem is that for some reason the `#pbody` is not being found by the javascript bit, therefore generating the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mediacitizens.companyapp.presentation.desktop.SlideshowController$1.changed(SlideshowController.java:165)
    at com.mediacitizens.companyapp.presentation.desktop.SlideshowController$1.changed(SlideshowController.java:1)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:196)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:100)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:195)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:161)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:130)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:163)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.updateState(WebEngine.java:975)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.dispatchLoadEvent(WebEngine.java:1086)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.access$600(WebEngine.java:968)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$PageLoadListener.dispatchLoadEvent(WebEngine.java:955)
    at com.sun.webpane.platform.WebPage.fireLoadEvent(WebPage.java:2372)
    at com.sun.webpane.platform.WebPage.fwkFireLoadEvent(WebPage.java:2220)
    at com.sun.webpane.webkit.network.URLLoader.twkDidFinishLoading(Native Method)
    at com.sun.webpane.webkit.network.URLLoader.access$1300(URLLoader.java:42)
    at com.sun.webpane.webkit.network.URLLoader$6.run(URLLoader.java:657)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:73)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

The `SlideshowController.java:165` being the line:

```
maincontainer.setAttribute("style", String.format("-webkit-transform: scale(%.5f)", (primaryScreenBounds.getHeight() / 768.0)));
```

I cannot understand the reason behind this behavior.

---

**Update**: I tried waiting for the document to load but it doesnt work either, first I put this manually in the content:

```
<script>
function scaleBody(scale)
{
    alert(3);
    document.getElementById('pbody').style.webkitTransform = "scale("+scale+")";
}
</script>
```

and then, using the state change listener:

```
double scale = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getHeight() / 768.0;
wv.getEngine().executeScript(String.format("alert(1); window.onload = function(){ alert(2); scaleBody(%.5f); }", scale));
```

Only `alert(1)` actually fires and no errors are generated...

...still dont know how to execute js in JavaFX.

Comment: Why not to execute a JS function taking a scale values as parameter?

Comment: To be honest I am not aware of such function, is it a standard JS one or Webkit-specific?

Comment: Both of them. Any JS code that webkit's engine can handle. What I mean try writing a JS function in a <script> tag block that does document.getElementById() and further. Then call this funtion in wv.getEngine().executeScript().

Comment: I should probably say that I dont have much control over the content, its being fetched via external service.

Comment: I am no JavaFX expert. But, it could be because you trying to access the body when the body hasn't even loaded. First, be certain that the body has finished loading when your initialize() executes. I doubt it is.

Comment: I tried utilising `window.onload` to wait for the body to load, with no result... check the update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide more details like what kind of html content are you trying to load. Here is my test code that works fine as expected:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker.State;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class WVTest extends Application {

    private WebView wv;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        wv = new WebView();
        wv.getEngine().load(this.getClass().getResource("index.html").toExternalForm());
        // wv.getEngine().load("http://www.oracle.com/products/index.html");
        wv.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
                new ChangeListener<State>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> ov, State oldState, State newState) {
                        if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                            wv.requestFocus();
                            wv.getEngine().setUserStyleSheetLocation(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
                            Rectangle2D primaryScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
                            Element maincontainer = (Element) wv.getEngine().executeScript("document.getElementById('pbody')");
                            System.out.println("maincontainer = " + maincontainer);
                            maincontainer.setAttribute("style", String.format("-webkit-transform: scale(%.5f)", (primaryScreenBounds.getHeight() / 768.0)));
                        }
                    }
                });

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(wv);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

with *style.css*

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#pbody {
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
}
```

and *index.html*

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body id="pbody">
    Test<br/>
    Test<br/>
    Test<br/>
    Test<br/>
</body>
</html>
```

The line

```
System.out.println("maincontainer = " + maincontainer);
```

prints

> maincontainer = [object HTMLBodyElement]

Alternatively open the html content you load in a regular web browser then press F12 (firebug or similar tool) and on JS console, type `document.getElementById('pbody')`.